# Horizontal Bar Chart Ignores tickInterval, min and max Options

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, jqplot

I have been using jqPlot for a project I am in and so far I am quite satisfied with it. Is very complete. However, the feature I am working on right now requires an horizontal bar chart. My issue is that my chart currently shows xaxis ticks as decimal numbers increasing by 0.5. I don't need decimal values. I need integers increasing by 1. My config is a little something like this:

```
var chartConfig = {
    seriesDefaults: {
        showMarker: false,
        shadowAngle: 135,
        pointLabels: {
            show: true,
            labelsFromSeries: true,
            seriesLabelIndex: 2,
            edgeTolerance: -50
        },
        renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
        rendererOptions: {
            barWidth: 25,
            barPadding: 0,
            barDirection: 'horizontal'
        }
    },
    axes: {
        xaxis: {
            min: 0,
            max: 4,
            tickInterval: 1
        },
        yaxis: {
            showTicks: true,
            renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
            tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
            tickOptions: {
                angle: -50,
                labelPosition: 'middle'
            }
        }
    }
};
```

However, looks like jqPlot is completely ignoring the xaxis tickInterval, min and max option values. My output chart looks as follows:

[image: Bad Chart]

I need to know what I am doing bad here. My config looks to be okay, but I can't get jqPlot to use the values I pass for the X axis. Any help on this matter will be very much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have been having problem with the tickInterval on horizontal bars also. I found that you have to specify both the min and max along with the tick interval for the axis you need it for.

This you have done but I wanted to state this somewhere as I spent a long time trying to find why tick interval wasn't working and this post kept coming up in my searches so hopefully it will help others.

For your issue, is possibly something to do with your data sets.

If this is still causing you problems maybe post the full script with your values as the code is only partial atm.

Thanks

Richard