# Force ticks to be whole numbers

Tags: jqplot

Exactly the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12000202/horizontal-bar-chart-ignores-tickinterval-min-and-max-options), but since I don't have the reputation to upvote it (and can't answer it), I'm going to have to ask it again...

Given a graph like the following, how can I force the ticks to always be whole numbers, even if the graph is empty? At the moment, if there is no data for the graph, it will go `0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0`, but in the context of this graph, that makes no sense - what is being displayed can only consist of whole numbers. If the numbers involved are very small, it can occasionally display as, e.g., `1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 3.5` (etc), which again is not ideal. As the graph represents things that have happened over the course of the day, it will start out at zero each day and slowly grow, resetting to zero the next day. Ideally, I would like the ticks to start out at `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5`, and then scale appropriately with the data.

Any suggestions? I've tried `tickInterval: 1` (and `5` and `50`...) in both the X and Y axes, but that didn't seem to do anything... Maybe a bug in JQPlot?

EDIT: [JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/32QBL/3/) showing the problem.

```js
$.jqplot('chartdiv', [ data.a, data.b ], {
    title : "Title",
    stackSeries : true,
    seriesDefaults : {
        renderer : $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
        rendererOptions : {
            barMargin : 15,
            barDirection : 'horizontal'
        },
        pointLabels : {
            show : true,
            stackedValue : false
        },
    },
    seriesColors : [ "#651811", "#126542" ],
    axesDefaults : {
        tickRenderer : $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
        tickOptions : {
            fontSize : '8pt'
        }
    },
    axes : {
        xaxis : {
            label : "X-Label",
        },
        yaxis : {
            renderer : $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
            ticks : [ "T1", "T2", "T3", "T4" ],
            tickOptions : {
                angle : -75
            },
            label : "Y-Label",
            labelRenderer : $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer,
            labelOptions : {
                angle : -90
            },
        }
    },
    highlighter : {
        show : false,
        showTooltip : false,
    },
    legend : {
        show : true,
        location : 'e',
        placement : 'outside',
        labels : [ 'L1', 'L2' ]
    }
});
```

Comment: What's does data.a and data.b equal?  I started a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/32QBL/1/, but can not replicate your problem with dummy data.

Comment: I've updated the fiddle with values that show the problem. If that update isn't saved for everyone, then the graph data should be `[ [[0,1],[0,2],[0,3],[0,4]],[[0,1],[0,2],[0,3],[0,4]] ]`. Hopefully that makes it clearer. Edit: See http://jsfiddle.net/32QBL/3/

Answer (score 0):

You might have better luck setting the max and min values for the axis, then let JQPlot fill in the tick values.

```
// This is YOUR data set
var series = [882, 38, 66, 522, 123, 400, 777];

var max;

if (series.length > 0) {
    // Instead of letting JQPlot pick the scale on the y-axis, let's figure out our own.
    var series_max =  Math.max.apply(null, series);
    var digits = max.toString().length;
    var scale = Math.pow(10, max_digits - 1);

    max = (Math.ceil(series_max / scale)) * scale;
} else {
    // Since you sometimes have an empty dataset, then just pick an arbitrary max.
    max = 10;
}

$.jqplot(
    'foo',
    [series],
    {
        axes: {
            yaxis: {
                min: 0,
                max: max
            }
        }
        // Put your other config stuff here
    }
)
```

This basic approach works for any integers. If you are using floats and they are greater than 1, you can still use this approach by casting your "series_max" to int. If you are using floats less than 1, this approach may not be suitable: it will always pick 1 as the y-axis max.